# Как описать внутри функции модуля глобальную переменную из вызывающего модуля

Tags: python, модули, global-variables, модульность

Вот структура модулей:

главный (main):

```
from globals_module import *

global global_dict
global_dict = dict.fromkeys(["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"])

def fun0():
    # global global_dict
    fun1()


fun0()
```

вызываемый  ***'globals_module.py'***:

```
global global_dict


def fun1():
    # global global_dict

    def fun2():
        # global global_dict
        global_dict["a1"] = 4

    fun2()
```

При вызове выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\AnaPy\examples_code\global_main.py", line 17, in <module>
    fun0()

  File "D:\AnaPy\examples_code\global_main.py", line 14, in fun0
    fun1()

  File "D:\AnaPy\examples_code\globals_module.py", line 17, in fun1
    fun2()

  File "D:\AnaPy\examples_code\globals_module.py", line 15, in fun2
    global_dict["a1"] = 4

NameError: name 'global_dict' is not defined
```

Я конечно понимаю, что глобальные это плохо.
Вызвано тем, что модуль `tkinter`  не позволяет передавать параметры внутрь функций,  назначенных на клавиши. вот и закрутилось.

По "физике" - это вызов формы при обработке подменю главного меню.

Проблема в том, что `global` внутри модуля выводит на уровень этого модуля.
А мне надо бы еще выше.
Что посоветуете?

А то я уже готов в базу писать эти переменные и читать оттуда....
Ну или держать весь код в одном модуле...

Я вроде все 32 варианта включения/выключения `global` перепробовал - ни один не сработал ))

Comment: `Вызвано тем, что модуль tkinter не позволяет передавать параметры внутрь функций, назначенных на клавиши. вот и закрутилось.` - вообще-то можно лямбду использовать, в которую передать параметр по умолчанию, что-то типа `Button(master, text="text", command=lambda param=param: some_function(param))` - это довольно расхожая практика. Глобальные переменные - зло, и уж точно вызываемый модуль не должен ничего знать о глобальных переменных вызывающего модуля.

Comment: @insolor  А передать выбранное значение из выпадающего списка назад по цепочке?
Есть распространенное решение?
Подскажете?

Comment: Нужно описание исходной проблемы, сейчас по вашему вопросу и по комментарию проблематично восстановить, что конкретно вам на самом деле нужно)

Comment: 3 файла сделай. в одном уже объявленные переменные, а два других его импортят и меняю там все что надо. с двумя файлами тоже можно и неоправданно сложно. глобальные переменные это зло, если руки из жопы. автомобиль тоже зло, им можно можно навредить себе и другим, но никто его не запрещает и оружием массового поражения не называет.

Comment: @alex, автомобиль не зло, если пользоваться им правильно. Вот нештрафуемый порог скорости и "скидка" при быстрой оплате штрафа - зло (поощряет гонять по городу со скоростью 80 км/ч), в итоге это приводит к количеству жертв на дорогах как в небольшой войне. Так же и с глобальными переменными. Сами по себе они может и не зло (в определенных пределах), а вот предполагаемый обмен данными между модулями в две стороны через глобальные переменные - очень плохое архитектурное решение, приводит к сильному связыванию и запутыванию кода.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, подойдет ли такой вариант именно в вашей ситуации, но можно так попробовать изменить файл global_module

```
def fun1():
    fun1.global_dict = {}
    
    def fun2():
        fun1.global_dict["a1"] = 4
    fun2()
```

Comment: это совсем не то )